Who where these commentaries of the book chovot Halevavot?
BH
Who where these comentaries Pat Lechem, Marpe La Nefesh, and Tov Halevanon? And is Tov Halevanon the same as Lev Tov on Chovot Halevavot?
Also heard there is also Nedar Bakodesh on Chavot Halevavot so who was he and what are the significant other comentaries on this book?


"And is Tov Halevanon the same as Lev Tov on Chovot Halevavot?" No. According to Hebrew Wikipedia Tov Halevanon was written by Israel Zamosz, and Lev Tov by R. Pinchas Lieberman. The Hebrew Wikipedia article, also has short biographical descriptions about the other commentaries you mention (mainly about their respective authors).
